# Change FPS on video capture from file with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video, frame-rate

I'm reading a video file, and it's slower than the actual FPS of the file (59 FPS @1080p) even if i'm not doing any processing to the image:

```
       using namespace cv;
       using namespace std;
       // Global variables
        UMat frame; //current frame
        int main(int argc, char** argv)
        {

                VideoCapture capture("myFile.MP4");
                namedWindow("Frame");
                capture.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, 120); //not changing anything
                cout>>capture.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
                while (charCheckForEscKey != 27) {

                       capture >>frame;
                if (frame.empty())
                    break;
                imshow("Frame", frame);

                }

    }
```

Even if I tried to set CAP_PROP_FPS to 120 it doesn't change the fps of the file and when I get(CAP_PROP_FPS) I still get 59.9...

When I read the video the actual outcome is more or less 54 FPS (even using UMat).

Is there a way to read the file at a higher FPS rate ?

I asked he question on the opencv Q&A website as well :http://answers.opencv.org/question/117482/change-fps-on-video-capture-from-file/

Is it just because my computer is too slow ?

Comment: Search the internet for "double buffering", a concept where one thread is writing a buffer while another thread is reading a buffer.  Multiple buffers can be used to adjust for speed.

Comment: Reading from a file, the FPS is just metadata that you may use. `VideoCapture` just decodes the frames as fast as it can.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks I'm goin to check

Comment: @DanMašek, thanks, but how come using a regular videoReader I get a faster display (VLC for example) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR FPS is irrelevant to the problem, probably a performance issue

**What FPS is used for?** Before you can display a single frame of video, you have to read the data (from an HDD, DVD, Network, Internet or whatever) and decode it. Both of these operations take time, the amount of which differs from system to system, depending on the speed of HDD/Internet, processor speed etc. If we just display each frame as soon as it's ready, the resulting movie speed will, therefore, vary from system to system. That is usually not what we want, so along with the sequence of video frames we get the "frames per second" value (a. k. a. FPS), which tells us how soon we shall display each consecutive frame (once every 1/30-th of a second for 30 FPS, once every 1/60-th of a second for 60 FPS, etc.) If the frame is ready to be displayed but it's too early, we can wait till its time comes. If it's time to display a frame but it's not ready (on an underpowered/too busy system), there's not much we can do (maybe drop frames in some situations). To see the effect for yourself, try changing the FPS value for x2, saving the file and display it with VLC: for the same amount of data and same number of frame, you will notice that the speed of your video has doubled and the time - halved. Try writing each frame twice for your x2 FPS - you will see that the playback speed is back to normal (with double the number of frames and meaningless increase of the file size).

**What FPS is not used for?** When processing (not displaying) a video, we are not limited by the original FPS, and the processing goes as fast as it can. If your PC can process 1000 frames per second - good, if 1500 - even better. Needless to say, changing the FPS value in the file won't improve your CPU/HDD speed, so if you were only able to process 54 frames per second, you are still going to be able to only process 54 frames per second.

**But how can VLC display faster?** Assuming you didn't forget to switch from Debug to Release build before measuring time, there are still a number of possibilities: VLC is probably better optimized for the particular task of video playback (OpenCV is not really that fast at some tasks, plus it has to convert each frame to a more general Mat/UMat structure), multithreading (including "double buffering", as mentioned in the comments) is another possible reason, maybe caching as well (e. g. reading a block of data containing many frames from the HDD at once instead of reading and processing frames one by one).